# How do I capture the latest GitHub release of a project from the API?

Tags: github

I am trying to grab the download url of latest release from GitHub [API page](https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest).

I first need to capture all the lines which start with `browser_download_url` and further grab the one having `linux64` in them.

Target link currently which it should capture - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz

After some research , i tried doing the following -

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest | grep "browser_download_url | grep 'linux64[.]gz' | head -n 1 | cut -d '"' -f 4
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Also it doesn't necessarily have to be an edit of my attempt, I don't mind if awk, sed etc are used in answers

Comment: you can refer to external links to support your question, but please add sample input and expected output to the question itself for clarity and easy testing purposes

Comment: Use 'jq', not grep. It's JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest' | 
    jq -r '.assets[].browser_download_url' |
    grep linux64

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz
```

Comment: I tried it but the file.json is empty for some reason